# vscode c++ intellisense finds unrelated yocto sysroots for alternative definitions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using `cpptools` coming with the VsCode and this project is one developed for embedded ARM using yocto. For development, I develop and test on local x64 machine. Then I build and deploy through yocto.

My problem is that, I get a lot of include errors because cpptools finds a lot of different alternative includes from my yocto sysroots. I configured cpptools to use my local `compile_commands.json` and there is nothing in my `IncludePath` settings related to yocto sysroots as well.

Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
            "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compileCommands": "/path_to/compile_commands.json",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Since my yocto sysroot is not mentioned anywhere in `compile_commands.json` as well, I have no idea how it finds those. In the past, out of frustration with intellisense, I added yocto sysroots to `IncludePath` at some point but as you can see, it is removed now. After that, I recreated intellisense database many times and it should have forgotten about yocto sysroots long ago.

The question remains, how cpptools finds my yocto sysroots for possible includes with these settings? Is this due to a setting or database captured in the past that is not properly deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why VsCode was able to see all those yocto folders for possible include paths but following solved the problem for me.

To be able to use intellisense in VsCode `cpptools` with `compile_commands.json`, you need to have a `clangd` installation in your path. I had `clangd-9` installed but it was not symlinked to `/usr/bin/clangd` and I suppose thats where VsCode looks for it. So, just make sure that you have valid `clangd` in `/usr/bin/clangd`